# Can I call same endpoints with the same Scatter-Gather?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I know that http requests called in scatter gather are independent of each other. But what if all the endpoints are the same in the scatter-gather. Does the end-points also work independently??

In my Project I need to call the same endpoint more than once, yes I can pass the overall value as payload by calling only one time. But the system-layer is made to be generic and is not in my hands. Can I use scatter-gather for this multiple call of same endpoints?

Comment: The question is too open and provides too little details and it will tend to receive answers based on opinion rather than facts. Such questions and answers are discouraged in Stackoverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more details. Having said that, in general HTTP Requests do not care if they are to the same URL or a different one. And the Scatter Gather doesn't care what is inside its routes. You may still find other issues with this design not directly related to the scenario mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think scatter-gather is the right way to handle your requirement. What you can do is use for each / parallel for each and loop through all your sys api requests , store the responses and process it further.

Comment: The answer misses to provide a reasoning as to why the proposed solution is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Solution - 1: For good performance, Use batch processing and in the batch aggregator, you can set the size and process further.

Solution - 2: Use For each to do the sys call multiple times.